# NodeJS how to handle (stop running) import attempt of entrypoint from another module

Tags: node.js

As much as I know, if I want to eliminate the option of importing my entrypoint in Node, I should write something like:

```
if (require.main !== module) { ... }
```

What's the difference between using a return statement and process.exit(1)?

Should I use one of those or it was all wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

- Return would simply stop the processing of the rest of the code in the module. The program would latter fail when accesses to the attributes of the module propagate undefined. (I think that this might only work in Node.js modules and not in other Node implementations or in other modules systems for node if they don't permit a return outside a function because they don't use the function wrapper that the Node.js modules do.)
- process.exit would end the process but wouldn't tell the user why.

Another option that I think would be better is to throw an exception. This could carry a message and it would end the program if not caught.